# JAXB : Is the annotation @XmlAccessorType is only for Serialization and nothing to do with Binding of data?

Tags: jaxb

I wanted to know why do we need to specify the Annotation @XmlAccessorType when working with JAXB .

When i googled for this  i found out this description from a  website stating this 
**@XmlAccessorType sets default field and property serializability. By default, JAXB serializes public fields and properties. By setting @XmlAccessorType, the bean can choose to only allow annotated fields to be serialized.**

Here the author mentions that with this annotation it gives control on  serialization .

My question is , so @XmlAccessorType has  nothing to do with the JAXB Binding and Unbinding from XML to java and java to XML , and it is all about Serialization only .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JAXB's `@XmlAccessorType` annotation is only used by [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations for determining how to marshal a file to/from XML:

Normally the main decision to be made is between `FIELD` & `PROPERTY`/`PUBLIC`.  `FIELD` is particularly useful when you have logic in your get/set methods that you do not want triggered during marshalling/unmarshalling.  To see one way this choice affects the mapping metadata see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

`NONE` is a useful choice when you have many unmapped properties and you want to tell your JAXB implementation to only map the fields/properties you have annotated.  This can be alot easier than adding a lot of `@XmlTransient` annotations into your model.

**Fore More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html